# How to interpret Dill's pickling trace output in Python? (Profiling (un)pickling / (de)serialization bottlenecks)

Tags: python, serialization, profiling, pickle, dill

I'm trying to use dills' `dill.detect.trace(True)` functionality - which prints a trace during pickling - to find out why my unpickling process is so slow. I haven't found a way to output the trace for unpickling, but I am assuming this is more or less the 1-to-1 reverse process of pickling, and that inspecting the pickling trace should thus reveal bottlenecks which also hold for unpickling.

I don't know how to interpret its output, however. For example:

```
T4: <class 'foo_package.base.model.BarModel'>
# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7f7de3832800>
T4: <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>
# T4
T4: <class 'foo_package.some_module.Bar'>
# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7f7d206273c0>
T4: <class 'some_package.some_module.Bar.options.SessionOptions'>
# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7f7d20384040>
T4: <enum 'ModelType'>
# T4
T4: <enum 'SomeOtherEnum'>
# T4
# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x7f7d206b9ac0>
# D2
T4: <class 'some_package.some_other_module.XyzzyObject'>
# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7f7d206cb100>
###... and so on...
```

How should one interpret `D2` and `T4`? And what do the `#` prefixes mean? Can hints be found on the existence of cyclical references/deeply nested structures which increase (de)serialization time?

Dills documentation on the `trace` function merely states:

> trace(boolean)
>
> ```
> print a trace through the stack when pickling; useful for debugging
> ```

**Further context**:
(lowering risk of XY problem)

I'm using dill to store a partial state of a python program's instances in order to save an analytical model.

(Un)pickling has become very slow over time, and I'm trying to identify the cause.

I have already delegated storage of objects with dedicated serialization methods (e.g. numpy/pyarrow/pandas objects) to other serialization methods using `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` for objects containing significant amounts of data. This helped a little, but it still takes 1 to 2 minutes to deserialize, which slows down the debugging process quite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the dill author.
This is copied from the README on GitHub and PyPI...

To aid in debugging pickling issues, use *dill.detect* which provides
tools like pickle tracing::

```
>>> import dill.detect
>>> dill.detect.trace(True)
>>> f = dumps(squared)
F1: <function <lambda> at 0x108899e18>
F2: <function _create_function at 0x108db7488>
# F2
Co: <code object <lambda> at 0x10866a270, file "<stdin>", line 1>
F2: <function _create_code at 0x108db7510>
# F2
# Co
D1: <dict object at 0x10862b3f0>
# D1
D2: <dict object at 0x108e42ee8>
# D2
# F1
>>> dill.detect.trace(False)
```

With trace, we see how `dill` stored the lambda (`F1`) by first storing
`_create_function`, the underlying code object (`Co`) and `_create_code`
(which is used to handle code objects), then we handle the reference to
the global dict (`D2`).  A `#` marks when the object is actually stored.

Comment: See: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thank you. It might be worth it to add this information to the documentation as well for this function. I would expect the documentation to contain more detailed information than the README (I may have missed a place in the documentation elsewhere where this is covered, although my google fu didn't find it). On an unrelated note; my thanks also for developing this package; you've helped a lot of people.

Comment: You are right. The README is the only place it's covered in the docs.